# Use tw elements in a NextJS project

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I'm trying to use tw-elements in a `nodejs` project. If I follow their [documentation](https://tailwind-elements.com/quick-start/) and just import tw-elements in my _app, I get this error:

`ReferenceError: document is not defined`

I found a stackoverflow response that said to put this at the start of the index.min.js file of tw-elements:

`if (typeof window == "undefined")return;`

I did and the error disappeared, but the library still won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try dynamic import, worked well for me in many situations where document / window was not defined. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

Comment: Doesn't work with dynamic import :(

It gives the same error with undefined

Comment: Maybe you should follow this guide https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Comment: That's for tailwindcss, not for tw-elements

Comment: Check the answer from this question as a reference, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73342930/how-to-import-js-file-in-next-js-pages/73344201#73344201

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add Tailwind Elements using these NPM steps [here](https://tailwind-elements.com/quick-start/#:%7E:text=it%20will%20work.-,NPM,-NPM%20is%20a).

Here is how to get it to work with Nextjs:

First step is to add this code to your `_app.js` file:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const use = async () => {
      (await import('tw-elements')).default;
    };
    use();
  }, []);
```

Like this for example:

```js
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const use = async () => {
      (await import('tw-elements')).default;
    };
    use();
  }, []);
return (
```

Make sure you add `import { useEffect } from "react";` to the top of `_app.js`.

It’s also important that you’re not importing Tailwind Elements anywhere else expect for the `_app.js` file.

Tailwind Elements should now be working!

Comment: Please, I did what you are saying but still no component from tw-elements works for me. I am using Nextjs 13 and all these errors show up: Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style'), TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeAttribute'),TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute'),Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeAttribute')

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. I followed Tyrell Curry's answer but It encountered type not found error because I was using typescript.
Unfortunately the type definitions were missing for tailwind-elements library.

I made a little change it the function so that type check have to be avoided by using as any.

```
useEffect(() => {
 const use = async () => {
  (await import("tw-elements" as any)).default;
 };
use();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using the package `Collapse` and tweaked the other answers to import the specific package and call it. Worked perfectly fist time!

```
useEffect(() => {
  const initTE = async () => {
    const { default: initTE } = await import('tw-elements');
    const { Collapse } = await import('tw-elements'); // Import the Collapse component if needed
    initTE({ Collapse }); // Call the initTE function with the Collapse component
  };
  initTE();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ddi why you suggest with useeffect for importing "tw-elemnts"however, it remains unworking.
i try to paste any code from tw-elements and nothig works

```
 content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{html,js}",
    "./node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/**/*.js",
    "./node_modules/react-tailwindcss-datepicker/dist/index.esm.js",
  ],
  plugins: [require("tw-elements/dist/plugin"), require("@tailwindcss/forms")],
```

Answer (score 0):

For those still having issues with other answers, you can use this style of loading to make tw-elements work with NextJS:

```js
// initialize tw-elements, we have to use this hack since tw-elements requires document to be defined which
// isn't the case when using SSR
useEffect(() => {
  const _initTE = async () => {
    const use = (await import('tw-elements')).initTE;
    const { Chart } = await import('tw-elements');
    use({ Chart });
  };
  _initTE();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

**updated solution using Next.js 13.4.10 AppRouter**

To use the component without errors, **you must dynamically import with no server-side rendering.**
see this page.tsx

```tsx
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const ButtonDy = dynamic(() => import("./mycomponents/Button"), {ssr: false});

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <ButtonDy>Epic Button</ButtonDy>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Here is the 'Button.tsx' component:

```tsx
'use client'

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { initTE, Ripple } from "tw-elements";

const Button: React.FC<{
  children?: React.ReactNode,
}> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    initTE({ Ripple });
  }, []);
  return(<>
    <button
      type="button"
      data-te-ripple-init
      data-te-ripple-color="light"
      className="inline-block rounded bg-primary px-6 pb-2 pt-2.5 text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-normal text-white shadow-[0_4px_9px_-4px_#3b71ca] transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:bg-primary-600 hover:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] focus:bg-primary-600 focus:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-primary-700 active:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] dark:shadow-[0_4px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.5)] dark:hover:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)] dark:focus:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)] dark:active:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)]">
      {children}
    </button>
  </>);
}

export default Button;
```

original solution on Tailwind Elements Docs https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/integrations/next-integration/