# how to import js file in next.js pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

can we import bootstrap.bundle.js file directly from node_modules/boostrap directory?

```js
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></Script>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

how can I point to `node_modules` directory inside the `src` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I started learning Next.js and was stuck adding Bootstrap Bundle JS. So, one can do this way using the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== undefined) {
      const bootstrap = require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')
    }
  })

  return (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```